# How to use a class function pointer in another class or struct?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I need to use a function defined in one class in another class. Instead of rewriting the whole function, I tried to pass the function as a pointer, as below:

```
class C {
  public:
    int get(int x) { return x*x; }
};

struct S {
    int (*func) (int x);
};

int main() {
    C c;
    S s;

    cout << c.get(3) << endl;

    s.func = &C::get;
    cout << s.func(3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work and gives the following error:

```
func_ptr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
func_ptr.cpp:42:18: error: cannot convert ‘int (C::*)(int)’ to ‘int (*)(int)’ in assignment
```

Is it possible to do something like this, and if so, how can I fix it? Moreover, if it is possible, can I use the pointer from an object instance instead of the class? That is, to possibly use variables defined in a specific class instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C::get()` is a non-static member function, which means it must be invoked on an instance of `C`. It has an implicit first argument, the `this` pointer, that must be passed to it when calling the function.

Since your `C::get()` doesn't seem to need access to any data members of `C`, you could make it a `static` member function.

```
static int get(int x) { return x*x; }
```

Now your code will work as is.

---

Another option is to change `func` so that it is a pointer to a member function of `C`

```
struct S {
    int (C::*func) (int x);
};
```

And invoke it as

```
s.func = &C::get;
std::cout << (c.*(s.func))(3) << std::endl;
```

---

Yet another option would be to change the type of `S::func` to `std::function<int(int)>`. Now it can hold any *callable* (function pointer, functor, lambda) that takes a single `int` as an argument, and returns an `int`.

```
struct S {
    std::function<int(int)> func;
};

s.func = std::bind(&C::get, &c, std::placeholders::_1);
std::cout << s.func(3) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I ended up going with #3, since it allows me to use instance variables in c. Thanks for explaining it!

Comment: I have been looking all day for a way to invoke those pointers, this answer (specifically the second part) finally did it.

Answer (score 1):

A regular function and a member function are a bit different. To use a member function, you'll need an object to call it on (i.e. the this pointer in a member function body).

Take a look at std::function and std::bind, they are used to handle function like (callable) entities in a uniform way. They can manage global functions, static member functions, lambdas, regular member functions, functors, whatever that can be called like a function.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional

e.g.:

```
struct S
{
    std::function<int(int)> func;
};
C c;
S s;
s.func = std::bind( &C::get, &c, std::placeholders::_1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using STL then you can utilize std::function to hold a pointer to a function and std::bind to bind that particular pointer to a particular function. It makes your code look much more cleaner. std::bind looks for both static and non-static member functions. For non-static member function would need to pass the object reference so it will be able to point to the correct address.

Here is a code snippet to show how to use it:

```
std::bind(ClassName::MemberFunctionName, object, std::placeholders::_1)
```

std::placeholders::_1 means that ::MemberFunctionName accepts one parameter.